# How to automatically exit ssh 5 seconds after login?

Tags: bash, ssh, tmux

I have 30 servers doing a specific task inside a tmux session and I need to check each one of them by logging in and out of each server just to see what's going on in there. I want to do it automatically, it's something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

ip=(
    100.100.100.100
    200.200.200.200
    9.9.9.9
    )

for i in "${ip[@]}"; do
    # Login ssh, sleep for 5 seconds and then logout ssh automatically
done
```

How do I do this properly?

Comment: Perhaps you want [pssh](https://linux.die.net/man/1/pssh) ....

Comment: `ssh $i "sleep 5"`?

Comment: take a look at [*sexpect*](https://github.com/clarkwang/sexpect) with which u can start all the ssh connections in background and in the main script u just interate over the connections and print out the recent output.

Comment: If all you need to do is verify that the connection succeeds, just run something like `true` rather than sleeping for *any* amount of time.

Answer (score 0):

Seems a bit too easy, so perhaps I'm missing something in your question.

But take a look at this:

```
for i in $ip ; do
    (ssh $i "hostname; sleep 5"); echo "back to `hostname`"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [ansible](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/installation_guide/intro_installation.html) and the [ping module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/ping_module.html), for example:

```
$ ansible -m ping all
```

That will ping (ssh into all your hosts), you could create a basic [inventory](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html) and then target per host/groups as required.